# Apply regular expression repeatedly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex

I've got text expressions like this:

```
HIUPA:bla1bla1'HIUPD:bla2bla2'HIUPD:bla3bla3'HISYN:bla4bla4'
```

I want to extract the following text pieces:

```
HIUPD:bla2bla2'
```

And

```
HIUPD:bla3bla3'
```

My Objective-C code for this looks like this:

```
-(void) ermittleKonten:(NSString*) bankNachricht
{
    NSRegularExpression* regexp;
    NSTextCheckingResult* tcr;
    regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"HIUPD.*'" options:0 error:nil];

    int numAccounts = [regexp numberOfMatchesInString:bankNachricht options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [bankNachricht length])];
    for( int i = 0; i < numAccounts; ++i ) {
        tcr = [regexp firstMatchInString:bankNachricht options:0 range:NSMakeRange( 0, [bankNachricht length] )];
        NSString* HIUPD = [bankNachricht substringWithRange:tcr.range];
        NSLog(@"Found text is:\n%@", HIUPD);
    }
}
```

In the Objective-C code numAccounts is 1, but should be 2. And the string that is found is "HIUPD:bla2bla2'HIUPD:bla3bla3'HISYN:bla4bla4'"

I tested the regular expression pattern with an online tool ( http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html ). In the online tool it works fine and delivers 2 results as I want it to be.

But I would like to have the same result in the ios code, i.e. "HIUPD:bla2bla2'" and "HIUPD:bla3bla3'". What is wrong with the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing greedy matching with the `.*`, so the regular expression catches as much as it can in the `.*`. You should be doing `.*?`, or `[^']*`, so that the `*` can't match a `'`.